# Source for Kuiper theorem

Tags: vector-bundles, hilbert-spaces

I have now found a lot of sources, that state, that Kuipers Theorem implies, that any infinite dimensional Hilbert bundle over a CW complex is trivial and I know how to prove it. I would still prefer finding a single source, that proves this implication. Does someone know a such a source?

Comment: The proof that $GL(H)$ is contractible is quite compact.  From there it's just bundle nonsense -- that bundles are described in terms of classifying spaces.   Steenrod's book gives a fairly canonical proof of that.  Do you want something more streamlined for Hilbert bundles, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: No, I am Looking for a source, that just states "Any infinite dimensional Hilbert bundle over a CW complex is trivial." And then I jsut want to Quote that source and not have to write out the Details myself.

Comment: That statement is corollary 1 in Kuipers paper, but he does not spend words on it. Are you comfortable with citing that? Otherwise you can just state that any topological group $G$ is a principal $G$ bundle over a point via multiplication in the group. If $G$ is contractible then it follows that $BG=pt$. Principal $G$ Bundles over a CW complex correspond then correspond to homotopy classes into a point, of which there is only one. Hence all principal G-bundles over CW complexes are trivial. The statement for the associated fiber bundle follows.

Comment: It doesnt matter anymore. I finished my Thesis now.